Is there a way to use Chalice to run a specific task at a specific time?
I want to use AWS Chalice for my project, but one of the requirements I have is that I need to be able to "schedule" events i.e. send a text message to the user at a certain time say 3h15pm the next Saturday, but as far as I can see there's only functionality to schedule calling an event every x minutes.
Is there any functionality to use a specific datetime to call a given function, something similar to celery's apply_async's eta argument?

While Chalice itself may not directly support scheduling events at specific datetimes out of the box, integrating it with CloudWatch Events/EventBridge provides a flexible and scalable solution for scheduling tasks in AWS environments.
Keep in mind that CloudWatch Events/Eventbridge uses cron expressions to define schedules, so you'll need to familiarize yourself with cron syntax to specify the desired datetime for your scheduled events.
Given your requirement, "3:15 PM on the next Saturday," the cron expression would be:
15 15 * * 6

